# Why I am getting errors after adding importing AWS in angular?

Tags: angular16

I am trying to work with AWS in angular but at the very start after I install AWS-SDK:

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

After adding the below to my file-manager.ts, I am getting errors regarding node and stream.

```
import * as aws from 'aws-sdk';
```

I added the following as suggested buy the compiler:

```
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and then add 'node' to the types field in your tsconfig.
```

and still getting so many errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run following command

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

and then update tsconfig.json file and add the node types to the types array. If you don't have a types array, create one otherwise simply add 'node' in the array

```
"types": ["node"],
```

Comment: I did that but I don't have a types array, how to create one and where to place it?

Comment: why is it so hard to use aws-sdk with angular?

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", ...otherTypes],
    ...
  },}  inside compilerOptions like above you can add the types aaray. Not sure buddy probably it's not that hard.